# Javascript Clicker customer queue identify buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, button

I have the code below
Javascript and HTML

```js
function uppass () {
var element = document.getElementById("newclient");
var value = element.innerHTML;

++value;

console.log(value);
document.getElementById("newclient").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            clicked button in JavaScript
        </title>
    </head>

    <body style = "text-align:center;">
<header>
  <h1> Clicker customer queue identify button</h1>
</header>
<center>
  <button  id="c" class="button" onclick="uppass()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Common </button>
    <button id="f" type="button" onclick="uppass()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Fast </button>
    <button id="p" type="button" onclick="uppass()" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Priority </button>
</center>
<h5>Sua senha é:</h5><h2 id="newclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h5>
</body>
</html>
```

I am implementing buttons for a queue of customers, each button that is clicked will increase a number. Until then I managed to solve. I want to identify each button that is clicked.
For example. When clicking on `common`, the letter `c` appears in front of the number, when clicking on `fast` the letter `f` and `priority` the letter `p`. but the numbers are still in sequence.
For example. clicking buttons randomly
c - 1
f - 2
c - 3
p - 4
f - 5
f - 6
c-7
and so on.
I managed to make the buttons and count, but I can't identify each one. Can someone help? Thanks.

Code on [https://jsfiddle.net/t8y31fo5/](https://jsfiddle.net/markmark/t8y31fo5/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
function uppass (e) {
var element = document.getElementById("newclient");
   let value = element.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

++value;


 
let newValue=e.id +'--' +value ;
 


document.getElementById("newclient").innerHTML =  newValue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            clicked button in JavaScript
        </title>
    </head>

    <body style = "text-align:center;">
<header>
  <h1> Clicker customer queue identify button</h1>
</header>
<center>
  <button  id="c" class="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Common </button>
    <button id="f" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Fast </button>
    <button id="p" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Priority </button>
</center>
<h5>Sua senha é:</h5><h2 id="newclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h5>
 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: cool, but I want it to show up only on the screen, like in the friend's answer above. And it's opening a new box, like a new tab. look at the response from ikhvjs. I don't know if I managed to explain myself properly.

Comment: There it is, perfect. question solved, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use event delegation and it is more practical and you can pass an `event` inside the function and get the `id` from the `event`.

```js
document.querySelector("center").addEventListener("click", uppass);

function uppass(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "BUTTON") {
    const element = document.getElementById("newclient");
    let value = element.innerHTML.replace(/[^0-9]/g, "");

    ++value;
    element.innerHTML = `${event.target.id}-${value}`;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>clicked button in JavaScript</title>
  </head>

  <body style="text-align: center">
    <header>
      <h1>Clicker customer queue identify button</h1>
    </header>
    <center>
      <button id="c" class="button" style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px">
        Common
      </button>
      <button id="f" type="button" style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px">
        Fast
      </button>
      <button id="p" type="button" style="font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px">
        Priority
      </button>
    </center>
    <h5>Sua senha é:</h5>
    <h2
      id="newclient"
      style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px"
    >
      0
    </h2>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the element as a parameter to the function via `this` and get the parameter's `id` property:

```js
function uppass(t) {
  var element = document.getElementById("newclient");
  var value = newclient.innerHTML;
  ++value;
  console.log(t.id + "-" + value);
  document.getElementById("newclient").innerHTML = value;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <title>
    clicked button in JavaScript
  </title>
</head>

<body style="text-align:center;">
  <header>
    <h1> Clicker customer queue identify button</h1>
  </header>
  <center>
    <button id="c" class="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Common </button>
    <button id="f" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Fast </button>
    <button id="p" type="button" onclick="uppass(this)" style=" font-size: 16px; margin: 0 10px;"> Priority </button>
  </center>
  <h5>Sua senha é:</h5>
  <h2 id="newclient" style="font-size: 12px; display: inline-block; padding-left: 20px;">0</h5>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: cool, but I want it to show up only on the screen, like in the friend's response below. And it's opening a new box, like a new tab. look at the response from ikhvjs. I don't know if I managed to explain myself properly.